# &> redirection not working correctly

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Please see the following shell transcript:

```
$ ls
input.txt  test-amp-gt.sh  test-both-2.sh  test-both.sh  test-gt.sh

$ cat input.txt
input file

$ cat test-gt.sh
#! /bin/sh
cat input.txt > /dev/null && echo "DEBUG >"

$ ./test-gt.sh
DEBUG >

$ cat test-amp-gt.sh
#! /bin/sh
cat input.txt &> /dev/null && echo "DEBUG &>"

$ ./test-amp-gt.sh
DEBUG &>
$ input file
^C
$


$ cat test-both.sh
#! /bin/sh
cat input.txt > /dev/null && echo "DEBUG >"
echo "***"
cat input.txt &> /dev/null && echo "DEBUG &>"

$ ./test-both.sh
DEBUG >
***
DEBUG &>
$ input file
^C
$

$ cat test-both-2.sh
#! /bin/sh
cat input.txt &> /dev/null && echo "DEBUG &>"
echo "***"
cat input.txt > /dev/null && echo "DEBUG >"

$ ./test-both-2.sh
DEBUG &>
***
input file
DEBUG >
$
```

It was not clear to me as to why the redirect &> to /dev/null is apparently not working properly when the plain > is working fine. That is, in running test-amp-gt.sh, the contents of the text file should not have been output but they are. test-both-2.sh shows an even more curious behaviour of the &> -- the text should not have been output at all, but not only is it being output, but it is output *after* the output of the echo command on the next line!

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you aren't using `bash`, or another shell that understands `&>`. Notice the line at the top of your shell scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

These shell scripts will run with `/bin/sh`. On many systems that is symlinked to bash, but apparently not on yours. Most likely, it is `dash`, or some other lightweight alternative.

`&` is used to put commands in the background in shell scripts. Your shell is interpreting the `&` in `&>` with this meaning. So in `test-amp-gt.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh
cat input.txt &> /dev/null && echo "DEBUG &>"
```

It first starts `cat input.txt` in the background, then sees `> /dev/null` which it apparently ignores, and then runs `echo DEBUG &>`, which outputs as it should. Your script then completes, the shell you invoked `test-amp-gt.sh` from prints its prompt, and then the `cat` in the background outputs `input.txt`.

Comment: Thanks wingedsubmariner -- I later figured this out myself but unix.SE wouldn't let me answer my own question within 8 hours as I'm new to the site. Thanks for your kind help anyhow!