# Redirect output of nohup in a .sh file doesn't work properly

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, nohup

I want to run a lot of python scripts and save their outputs. Because running one by one in terminal is too cumbersome. As suggested, I decide to use a shell script (.sh).

To simplify the problem, let's say I have two python scripts to run (`print1.py` and `print2.py`). Script `print1.py` outputs number 1 and script `print2.py` outputs number 2.

#### If not using the shell script (i.e. enter commands separately), I can get the desired result.

If not using the shell script, the commands I would use are

```
$ nohup python print1.py &> 1.txt &
$ nohup python print2.py &> 2.txt &
```

which redirect the output to `1.txt` and `2.txt`, respectively. So `1.txt` would contain a number 1, and `2.txt` would contain a number 2. It works well if I enter these two commands separately in the terminal. **This is what I desired.**

#### Using the shell scipt, I can't get what I want (the redirection doesn't seem to work properly).

However, if I use a shell script, namely `command.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh
nohup python print1.py &> 1.txt &
nohup python print2.py &> 2.txt &
```

And I type

```
$ sh command.sh
```

to run `command.sh`. The output is not what I expected. `1.txt` and `2.txt` will be created, but they contain nothing. A `nohup.out` file will also be created, in which number 1 and 2 are included.

And the output shown on the terminal is

```
$ nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104191) suggests that with `#! /bin/sh`, some shells may not understand `&>`. So I also tried changing `#! /bin/sh` to `#! /bin/bash`. However,  it's also the same.

**Can I get the same result using a shell script, just as I enter the commands separately?**

Comment: If you explicitly type `sh command.sh`, you still have `sh` running the script. What happens with `bash command.sh`? Or if you make the script (with `#!/bin/bash`) executable and run `./command.sh`?

Comment: @DonHolgo Thanks, it works! The only difference between these two methods and typing command directly is that there won't be a `nohup: ignoring input` line at the beginning of file `1.txt` and `2.txt`. This doesn't affect the output, right? BTW, if you add  an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you explicitly say `sh command.sh`, `sh` is used to run your script, regardless of the `#!` line. However, as the linked answer says, `sh` doesn't understand `&>` as an operator of its own and reads

```
nohup python print1.py &> 1.txt &
```

as two commands:

```
nohup python print1.py &
> 1.txt &
```

The first one causes the output of `print1.py` to be written to `nohup.out`, the second one creates an empty `1.txt`.

If you want `bash` instead of `sh` to run your `command.sh`, you can either use

```
bash command.sh
```

or put `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` in the file, make it executable and then simply run

```
./command.sh
```

on its own.

Comment: Or use a compatible redirect: `> 1.txt 2>&1` instead of the bash-only shorthand.